# php echo not showing new lines stored in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with an input textbox that stores the content in the mysql database.

For example, I write in the input box:

```
Hello World!
Here is the new line
```

In the database, I find exactly the same text without any special characters ("here is..." starts in a new line in the database too).

When I call this data in a php echo, it shows it as:

```
Hello World! Here is the new line
```

What's wrong? How can I fix it? thanks

Comment: Hi Alessandro, we need to see your database code before we can help

Comment: Newlines don't show by default on a HTML page. You need to convert them to line breaks using [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br).

Comment: HTML doesn't show newline characters; you need to convert to an html break using `nl2br()`

Comment: Looks like a job for [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Database is quite simple. a table with few coloumns, one of them is a varchar  called "comment". I can't understand why the new line is correctly stored in the database but it's not showed correctly in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the database string to nl2br fucntion to get the new line as break rule in HTML.

```
<?php
$dbSQLValue = "Hello World!\nHere is the new line"; //string retrieved from SQL
echo nl2br($dbSQLValue);
?>
```

New lines are not converted directly to HTML break line.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open page source in browser and see that newlines are there, but for the browser to display them - they should not be `\n`s, but `<br>` tags or be inside a `<pre>` tag.

So: either convert newlines to `br`s via `nl2br($your_var)` or put the whole `echo` inside a `<pre>`.